# Yocto SWUpdate include RPi boot partition in update

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, raspberry-pi4, swupdate

On my RPi image, I have currently 4 partitions: boot, rootfs 1, rootfs 2 and persistent. I'm currently updating root partitions with standard dual copy update. But it means I'm not able update boot partition anymore. Is there some way, how to include boot partition into swu file or into rootfs? I'm not able to find boot partition file in deploy dir. Is there some config, where is specified, what filesystem images are generated?